# installing best and lasting ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, xorg

pls i av a hp laptop pavillon ze 4800ea 1ghz and 1gb  ram ,mobi amd athlon xp2500+™ what kind of ubuntu can i download then how
pls ansr fast.
 i want to use it for;
programming
graphics design
webdesign
software enginnering
online schooling.
  it run window xp profesaional with a free partition space of 9.5 gb.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with this laptop?  1gb ram isn't very much now a days for a GUI environment. ubuntu 16.04 can certainly run on such a device, but I doubt you are going to be happy. 12.04 is old enough that the apps on it might be happier with only 1GB, but while technically supported for a bit longer I don't think I could recommend it.

Comment: thanks i like this place, pls i want to learn programn improve my graphics design an develop soft wear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[LXLE](http://www.lxle.net/) or [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) might be good options for older laptops.  They are Ubuntu based distributions designed for low power systems.

Comment: LXLE is pretty much Lubuntu with a modified LXDE theme.